# Class breakdown + constructors

Tags: c#

Hi I am looking for some expert advice on how to break my class up.
Please bear with me this is the 5th week on c# im still fresh.
The task I got is to create a basic database and interface for a fiction company.
The interface shall support basic administration of members of the company.

The only rule is that there should be a split of at least 2 classes.

Now to my problem:
 - I use 8 members for the class in the constructor head? is there a better approach to do this?
 - Social nb in sweden is a date should I create a date class?.
 - If I create a get and set method for every member it will be a long document is there a   best practice?.

```
using System;

class Person
    {
    private string firstname, lastname, socialnb;
    private string email, phone;
    private string streetaddress, postcode, city;

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, string socialnb, string, email,      string phone, string streetaddress, string postcode, string city)
    {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.socialnb = socialnb;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.streetaddress = streetaddress;
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.city = city;
    }

    public String ToString() // Incomplete
    {
    return "\n\t"; // Will include all fields in the class
    }
```

}

Comment: You may use [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Comment: You could split it up in 
2 classes
eg. Person with firstname, lastname, email and phone
and Address with streetaddress postcode and city, which is inherited by person.

Comment: Most companies have employees and customers, not members.

Comment: @HenkHolterman srry for being unclear its a membership organisation

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a date class, In C# the DateTime class exists:

```
DateTime Socialnb;
```

you can set your date to current date using :

```
Socialnb = DateTime.Now;
```

When declaring your properties you can use :

```
public string firstname {get; set;} //it's like writing getter and setter in C#
```

For overriding the ToString() Method:

```
public String ToString()
{
return firstname + " " + lastname; //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify if you use windows forms or WPF for the UI.

You should use the #region ... #endregion to split your code and make it more clear (one for Properties, one for constructors, one for events... your choice)

The date class in dotnet is DateTime

About the members, if you need them outside of your class (which seems to be the case, because your class seems to be a Model class), you should make (auto)Properties. Example: public type name { get; set;} (see more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx))

Comment: I use windows forms is it hard to connect form to class

Comment: @Xiddic Windows forms is probably the easiest choice, it works like awt/swing in java. But WPF is useful to split your code in layers and allow graphic designers and programmers to work together smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

### Split class

You can divide your class in a following way:

```
using System;

class Person
    {

    public String FirstName {get; set;}
    public String LastName {get; set;}
    public String SocialNb {get; set;}

    public ContactInfo Contact {get; set;}
    public AddressInfo Address {get; set;}

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, string socialnb, string, email, string phone, string streetaddress, string postcode, string city)
    {
        Contact = new ContactInfo(email,phone);
        Address = new AddressInfo(streetaddress,postcode,city);
        FirstName = firstname;
        LastName = lastname;
        SocialNb = socialnb;
    }

    public String ToString() // Incomplete
    {
    return "\n\t"; // Will include all fields in the class
    }

class ContactInfo
{
    public String Email {get; set;}
    public String Phone {get; set;}

    public ContactInfo(String email = "", String phone = "") 
    { 
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
    }
}

class AddressInfo
{
    public String Street {get; set;}
    public String Postcode {get; set;}
    public String City {get; set;}

    public AddressInfo(String street = "", String postcode = "", String city = "") 
    { 
        Street = street;
        Postcode = postcode;
        City = city;
    }
}
```

### I use 8 members for the class in the constructor head - is there a better approach to do this?

There are several ways to initalize class members. You can use:

-Default parameters:

```
public Person(string firstname="", string lastname="", string socialnb="", string, mail="", string phone="", string streetaddress="", string postcode="", string city=""){}
```

-Object Initializer:

```
Person p = new Person 
{
   FirstName = "John",
   LastName = "Doe",
   Contact = new Contact { Email = "johndoe@dot.com", Phone="123432123"}
   // ... Initialize remaining field...
}
```

### Should I create a date class?

As you mentioned, socialnb is date in Sweden. If you want to keep your solution international, `String` would be the best option (because, basically, socialnb is always chain of numbers and/or symbols)

### If I create a get and set method for every member it will be a long document

You don't have to implement getter and setter for every member. Just use autoproperties:

```
public String Street {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better do it in two ways - 
1. create two separate classes (Person and Address) and keep the reference of Address in Person
OR
2. use nested class (learn more : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx)

Ex 1 :

1. Person
2. Address

Person

a. firstname
b. lastname
c. socialnb
d. email
e. phone

```
public class Person 
{ 

    // constructor takes only person specific data
    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, string socialnb, 
                  string, email, string phone) 
    {

    }

    // Address Property
    Public Address MyAddress {get; set;}

}
```

Address

a. streetaddress
b. postcode
c. city

```
public class Address
{
    public Address(string streetaddress, string postcode, string city)
    {

    } 
}
```

Ex 2:

```
public class Person
{

   //keep a reference of Address class
   public Address MyAddress {get; set;}

    public class Address
    {

    }
}
```